# Angular 2+ array asignment weird bug?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

The question is quite simple, but I haven't been able to find an answer.
When I try to reassign an element of an array of objects to another object that fits the description nothing happens, but when I first set the element to null and then reassign it, it works.
Here is the list of objects I'm using:

```
servers = [
{
  instanceType: 'medium',
  name: 'Production',
  status: 'stable',
  started: new Date(15, 1, 2017)
},
{
  instanceType: 'large',
  name: 'User Database',
  status: 'stable',
  started: new Date(15, 1, 2017)
},
{
  instanceType: 'small',
  name: 'Development Server',
  status: 'offline',
  started: new Date(15, 1, 2017)
},
{
  instanceType: 'small',
  name: 'Testing Environment Server',
  status: 'stable',
  started: new Date(15, 1, 2017)
}

];
```

Here is the approach that doesn't work:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    for (const i of value) {
      for (const j of value.slice(value.indexOf(i) + 1)) {
        if (i.name > j.name) {
          value[value.indexOf(i)] = j;
          value[value.indexOf(j)] = i;
        }
      }
    }
    return value;
  }

}
```

And here is the approach that does work:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    for (const i of value) {
      for (const j of value.slice(value.indexOf(i) + 1)) {
        if (i.name > j.name) {
          const index1 = value.indexOf(i);
          const index2 = value.indexOf(j);
          value[index1] = null;
          value[index2] = null;
          value[index1] = j;
          value[index2] = i;
        }
      }
    }
    return value;
  }

}
```

It's not a serious problem, but I'm curious now why it doesn't work one way, but does the other.
Thank you for your time!

**EDIT 1:** changed (i.name[0] > j.name[0]) to (i.name > j.name) for consistency. Both checks gave the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this

```
      value[value.indexOf(i)] = j;
      value[value.indexOf(j)] = i;
```

`value.indexOf(j)` on the second line returns what `value.indexOf(i)` used to be, because you've already put `j` in that slot. So you end up with

```
      value[value.indexOf(i)] = i;
```

which is a no-op.

If you need array values and indexes together when looping, you can use

```
 for (let [index, value] of array.entries())
```

instead of just `for..of`

Also, if you're just sorting your `servers` array by `name`, it might be much easier to use the built-in method:

```
 value.sort((x, y) => x.name.localeCompare(y.name))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the "mystery". I guessed it would be something simple, but always get stumped on these things anyway.

Answer (score 2):

the index, `i.name[0]` it's used when you implement old school for loops. i.e. `(for(var i=0, i > length, i++)`.

But the `for (const i of value)` is a build-in method, and when you call `i` it have already the value.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't check the code thoroughly it seems, but that part doesn't affect the result. I tried on both approaches with (i.name > j.name) and if (i.name[0] > j.name[0]). I'll edit the post to be consistent.